# How store user input into a text file and display all the data?

Tags: java

We have managed to get the code to display the first employee's details, however, the other 2 employee details have it been displayed. I am not sure how to append them. I am not sure if the printWriter is the right thing to out put the code and of not then, what would be best?

The code is below :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
    File employeeDetails = new File("Employees.txt");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(employeeDetails, true));

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Employees.txt", true);
        try{
            boolean repeat = false;

            System.out.println("Enter name: ");
            String name = scan.next();
            pw.println("name: " + name);

            System.out.println("Enter job title: ");
            String jobTitle = scan.next();
            pw.println("Job title: " + jobTitle);

            do{
                try{
                    System.out.println("Enter age: ");
                    int age = scan.nextInt();
                    pw.println("Age: " + age);
                    repeat = true;
                }
                catch(InputMismatchException ex){
                    System.err.println("Invalid age please enter a whole number."); 
                    scan.next();
                    continue;
                }
            }while(repeat==false);
            do{
                try{
                    System.out.println("Enter salary per year: ");
                    double salary = scan.nextDouble();
                    pw.println("Salary: " + salary);
                    repeat = false;
                }
                catch(InputMismatchException ex){
                    System.err.println("Invalid salary please enter a decimal."); 
                    scan.next();
                    continue;   
                } 
                catch(MissingFormatArgumentException ex){
                    System.err.println("Invalid salary please enter a decimal.");
                    scan.next();
                    continue;
                }
            }while(repeat);
        }finally{
            pw.close();
            fw.close();
        }
    }
    scan.close();
}
```

}

Comment: how is `fw` useful? you don't use it...

what happens when you run the code?

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: Sorry I haven't been on stack overflow in a while, I have managed to fix it, thank you for your help. I thought that by having the file writer and true at the end, that it would then append to the file i was writing

Answer (score 0):

So you problem is that each time in for loop you create a new file(deleting the other)

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Employees.txt", true);
```

put it outside

Comment: The file is created outside the loop and `pw` writes to that file. Here `fw` has no use

Comment: Also, since the append argument is true, it would not delete the file, even if it were used, right?

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet Yes and no, the file is recreated each time, but fw isn't being used

Comment: What's the use of the append argument if the file is being recreated each time?

Comment: @ItamarGreen The file is technically overwritten (i think). So yeah, it's still wrong

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to fix the code with all your help! A lot of the comments have been pointing at the file writer and I have moved it outside the loop. A few said that fw was unused, which I can now see, however, in a different situation, how would I be able to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `fw`:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Employees.txt", true);// remove this line

...
```

and also remove this line:

```
fw.close();
```

otherwise you'll get `NullPointerException`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise this was where I was going wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you keep closing pw.  Move the close of pw after the for loop.  I have modified your code and the following works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    File employeeDetails = new File("Employees.txt");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(employeeDetails, true));

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        //FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Employees.txt", true);
        try {
            boolean repeat = false;

            System.out.println("Enter name: ");
            String name = scan.next();
            pw.println("name: " + name);

            System.out.println("Enter job title: ");
            String jobTitle = scan.next();
            pw.println("Job title: " + jobTitle);

            do {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Enter age: ");
                    int age = scan.nextInt();
                    pw.println("Age: " + age);
                    repeat = true;
                } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                    System.err.println("Invalid age please enter a whole number.");
                    scan.next();
                    continue;
                }
            } while (repeat == false);
            do {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Enter salary per year: ");
                    double salary = scan.nextDouble();
                    pw.println("Salary: " + salary);
                    repeat = false;
                } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                    System.err.println("Invalid salary please enter a decimal.");
                    scan.next();
                    continue;
                } catch (MissingFormatArgumentException ex) {
                    System.err.println("Invalid salary please enter a decimal.");
                    scan.next();
                    continue;
                }
            } while (repeat);
        } finally {
            //pw.close();
            //fw.close();
        }
    }
    pw.close();
    scan.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for editing my code! I have managed to get it to work, and had no idea that that was the problem!